# Use Java Configuration in signed jar

Tags: java, spring, configuration

As part of the evolution of my software I'm trying to move Spring's configuration from XML to annotation-based configuration (I found it easier to manipulate certain configuration elements).

All works fine as long as I'm running unit tests in Maven, but when I'm trying to use the produced signed jar from another module of my project, I get errors stating that signer information from a CGLIB enhanced class doesn't match other classes in the same package.

Looking into the matter I could find that apparently Spring will always use CGLIB to enhance @Configuration classes, and then that CGLIB doesn't seem to play nice with signed jars since its dynamically created classes reside in the same package as the original.

Has anyone figured a way to use Java Configuration in signed jars ?

PS: I double checked the package name isn't present anywhere else ;)

Answer (score 1):

After raising this same issue on Spring JIRA (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12833), it appears that there is indeed a conflict between CGLIB and signed jars that impacts Spring-based application.

That said a simple workaround consists in using a @Component annotation on the class instead of @Configuration. I'm not 100% sure what the side effects could be but it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with AOP proxies which use CGLIB. I dug a little bit deeper and found out that this issue has been already solved in original CGLIB repository. I hope spring team will merge it into their version of CGLIB. Until they will fix it, I use my workaround with custom class loader for `ApplicationContext` with disabled security checks.
I described this solution in [my blog](http://dimafeng.com/2015/08/16/cglib/), I hope it'll be useful for somebody.